# THREE.js check if object is in frustum

Tags: three.js, frustum

i've been tinkering around with three.js and i have a canvas i'd like to use as kind of a GUI. for that i have to check if an object is in the camera frustum.

my current code:

```
camera.updateMatrix(); 
camera.updateMatrixWorld(); 
        
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
var projScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
        
frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix( camera.projectionMatrix );
        
if(frustum.containsPoint( mesh.position )){
    //stuff happens...
};
```

`frustum.containsPoint()`keeps returning false. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: A `Frustum` takes 6 `Plane`s as arguments, you're not providing anything. That's probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: So how would i go about cloning the camera frustum?

Comment: An example of that is in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858599/how-to-determine-if-plane-is-in-three-js-camera-frustum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is using

```
frustum.setFromMatrix( camera.projectionMatrix );
```

But that isn't the matrix you want. Instead use:

```
frustum.setFromMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse ) );
```

as answered in [How to determine if plane is in Three.js camera Frustum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858599/how-to-determine-if-plane-is-in-three-js-camera-frustum)

Answer (score 0):

Three.js is doing view frustum Culling internally and only rendering when in camera frustum. Assuming that your Boundig Volumes are calculated correct, you can track weather a renderable Object3D is inside the camera view frustum when Object3D.onBeforeRender callback is called in your current frame

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to find if a mesh is in camera view (within 100ms):

```
mesh.onBeforeRender = function() {
    if (mesh.userData.inViewID) clearTimeout(mesh.userData.inViewID);
    mesh.userData.inViewID = setTimeout(()=>{
        mesh.userData.inView = false;
        console.log("out of view");
    }, 100);
    if (!mesh.userData.inView) { 
        mesh.userData.inView = true;
        console.log("in view");
    }
}
```