# How to drag the scene in four direction using mouse?

Tags: three.js, mouseevent

Right now the whole the scene is rotating when moving the scene to left/right/top/bottom. I want to drag it in four directions.

http://arkatest.com/bbmap/map/test1.html

http://pastebin.com/KqQe1LhL

Comment: I would recommend staying away from THREEx extensions unless you're truly doing something that can't be done with Three.js alone that THREEx is solving. THREEx hasn't been updated in 2 years. Three.js is in Alpha and release sensitive. Instead, check out the examples folder which contains many controls examples that you can use right away: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/controls See specifically OrbitControls and TrackBallControls. There's a very simple example here: https://codepen.io/nireno/pen/cAoGI

Comment: From the SO guidelines: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. *

Comment: yeah i took the help of trackball controls and it worked perfectly @Radio

Comment: sure next time i will @gman

Answer (score 0):

You are using the trackballcontrols to manipulate the camera movement. The trackballcontrols has a pan functionality but it is triggered when right clicking with a mouse. This functionality is not configurable.

A very quick hack to enforce this would be changing [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js#L402) to

```
_state = STATE.PAN;
```

A better way would be to create a PR to three.js to make this mouse inputs configurable.

Comment: This works perfectly what i expected to do..! Thank You.

Comment: how to expect the same behavior with touch events @gero3

Comment: remove this code https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js#L504-L508

Comment: when i removed that code, the moment i touched the screen the scene is getting disappeared @gero3

Comment: i implemented one fingered touch pan and its working now @gero3

Comment: how to limit the scene pan to screen size so that it will not move beyond the scene.?  @Radio

Comment: @mahadevs - I am not quite sure what you mean. it may be a new question. However, this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858599/how-to-determine-if-plane-is-in-three-js-camera-frustum as soon as the center of the scene is out of frustrum, disable the pan controls with controls.noPan.